# Relationship between binomial and negative binomial distributions (how to extend the probability space?)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I wonder a technique to extend the discrete probability space.

Here's an example from *Concrete Mathematics* EXERCISE 8.17:

> Let $X_{n,p}$ and $Y_{n,p}$ have the binomial and negative binomial distributions, respectively, with parameters $(n,p)$. Prove that $\Pr(Y_{n,p}\le m) = \Pr(X_{m+n,p}\ge n)$.

The answer to the problem is also from *Concrete Mathematics*:

> \begin{align}
> \Pr(Y_{n,p}\le m) 
> &= \Pr(Y_{n,p}+n \le m+n) \\
> &= \hbox{probability that we need $\le m+n$} \tag{1}\\
> &= \hbox{probability that $m+n$ tosses yield $\ge n$ heads} \tag{2} \\
> &= \Pr(X_{m+n,p}\ge n)
> \end{align}

Well, (1) and (2) are describing the same thing, but they're in different probability spaces, so we should extend these two probability spaces into a unique probability space, ensuring that the probability of each event doesn't change. How can we do it? I haven't a clear idea.

And the more general problem arises: How to extend a probability space? Is there any technique to do it, at least, treat part of problems?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $X_{m+n,p}$ and $Y_{n,p}$ are all in different probability spaces, but we can define versions of them on the same probability space (technically this is known as **coupling**), by considering an infinite sequence of independent coin-flips with probability $p$ of heads in each one.

BTW, there seems to be some confusion here, due to different conventions for the negative binomial.  The definition as given in the text has $Y_{n,p}$ as the number of flips until the $n$'th head, while the question appears to use a different definition where $Y_{n,p}$ is the number of **tails** until the $n$'th head.  With the definition as given, the correct statement is that $\text{Pr}(Y_{n,p} \le m) = \text{Pr}(X_{m,p} \ge n)$.

EDIT: Oh, I see the problem.  I was looking at (8.59), and they're taking (8.60) as the
definition of the negative binomial.  So it is the number of tails.

Comment: The generating function of negative binomial distribution is $\displaystyle \left( \frac p {1-qz} \right)^n$, so it must be the number of tosses decreasing $n$.

Comment: Coupling, yes, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability) I'm educated.