# Sum of CDFs of Binomial and Pascal distribution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to prove that for a Binomial RV $x\sim \text{B}(n, p)$ and a Pascal RV $y\sim \text{NB}(k, p)$, their CDF (cumulative distribution function) ($F_X$ and $F_Y$) satisfies:
$$
F_X(k-1)+F_Y(n)=1
$$
I know that one can understand the result by considering a sequence of coin-flipping experiment, but I'm curious if one can show it by summing explicitly. I have tried it but there's no progress, so I would like to ask for help. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154236/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you, but I'm asking for an answer by _summing explicitly_.